# Get array value using Angular Dropdown

Tags: angular

I am trying to use Angular Dropdown. The JSON is as follows-

```
{
       { 
      "bookId":"1",
      "authors":{ "author1", "author2"}
       } 
       { 
      "bookId":"2",
      "authors":{ "author2", "author3"}
       } 
}
```

Have created a class named Book which stores the above values in Book Array named books.
In html code have the following -

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="book.id" (ngModelChange)='onBookSelected($event)'>  
            <option *ngFor="let book of books"
            [value] = "book.authors">{{book.id}}</option>
          </select>
```

In the component have the onBookSelected as follows-

```
onBookSelected(val: any)
{
  console.log(val);
}
```

I dont get the list of authors but get

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

I also tried creating an array of class author and using it as follows-

```
onBookSelected(authorList : any)
{
  console.log(authorList );
}
```

But get same output as

```
   [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Could someone please help to get list of authors when the book is selected from the dropdown. Thanks

Comment: Whats wrong with that? Author is an Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need do some changes in order get the authors

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedBookId" (ngModelChange)='onBookSelected($event)'>  
            <option *ngFor="let book of books"
            [value] = "book.id">{{book.id}}</option>
</select>
```

and then in the `onBookSelected($event)`

> **component.ts**

```
     let books=   {
           { 
          "bookId":"1",
          "authors":{ "author1", "author2"}
           } 
           { 
          "bookId":"2",
          "authors":{ "author2", "author3"}
           } 
     }

    onBookSelected(event){
       Object.values(this.books).forEach(book =>{
             if(book.bookId == this.selectedBookId){
                 console.log(Object.values(book.authors))
             }
       })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with that? Authors is an Object. However it think you wanted it to be an array

```
  "authors":[ "author1", "author2"]
```

That would print normally in the console.

if you do

```
onBookSelected(authorList : any)
{
  console.log(JSON.stringify(authorList));
}
```

it will print what you expected.

Comment: I still get [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] on using JSON.stringify